# Blockchain implementation

Tags: blockchain

I am new for blockchain, I want to implement blockchain in our new financial project where prediction will be shared between different parties. A lot of theoretical matter is available on the internet. But where we can start for implementation.

Comment: This is way too broad, and is arguably a offsite resource recommendation request. You need to narrow your question way down.

Comment: What language, OS do you prefer? See also Microsoft's COCO https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-microsoft-s-coco-framework-for-enterprise-blockchain-networks/

Comment: https://github.com/aprshenoy/SimpleBlockchain

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVqczFZr124 - videos from following channel are good reference for a start.

Comment: https://www.devteam.space/blog/how-to-integrate-a-blockchain-technology-into-your-project/  -  follow this guide, it will help you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It depends on the objective of the Blockchain that you want to start up. Also, it depends on if you want to have an open or a private Blockchain.

- If you want to start up a private Blockchain, i.e. the acces to the Blockchain is controled and the data isn't open, I suggest you to start reading about [Hyperledger Fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
- On the other hand, if you want to start up a public Blockchain, i.e. everyone would acces to the Blockchain and the would be open, I suggest you to start reading about [Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/token).

If you give more information about your idea, we could help you. Like Carcigenicate said, your question is too broad.

Comment: I would add Hyperledger Sawtooth as a possible private (or semi-private) blockchain solution. The Hyperledger Project homepage has some good information: https://www.hyperledger.org/

Comment: Yeah, that would be also great. There are many more, here a link where some of them are compared: http://radiostud.io/eight-blockchain-platforms-comparison/ However, there are other excelent entries in the Web comparing them.

Answer (score 3):

You can try exploring Ethereum and NEM for your purposes. The reason mainly is because a lot of financial institutions (startups to enterprise levels) are already either using or experimenting with them with great success.

If you want to create your own Blockchain implementation, try out either BigchainDB (https://www.bigchaindb.com/) or multichain (https://www.multichain.com). Both are open source platforms for creating your own blockchain implementation.

Answer (score 2):

To understand Blockchain just start with some Basic Theory but do more Practicals Here i am Share some of Links that will help you a lot ::
-> Decentralised Application by Siraj Rawal [Intro to Decentralized Apps](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2-dafEMk2A5VKD1CvdJMNIYerxoyPOcU)

-> Decentralised Application Book by Siraj Rawal 
[Decentralized Applications: Harnessing Bitcoin's Blockchain Technology](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01IO2VKHM/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1)

-> Also use some Block Chain Demo Application so that you can understand the working and concepts which is working behind the System -
[Blockchain Demo](https://anders.com/blockchain/)

-> The Most Part is to Understand the IPFS (InterPlanetary File System) it is the backbone of entire Blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

watch this tutorial, there is also the code to try it.

[Github - aymen94 | Simple-Blockchain](https://github.com/aymen94/simple-Blockchain)

Comment: @RohanAshik why are you going around changing links, and claiming this is "according to stackoverflow rules"? Where is the rule that dictates that raw links should be edited into the title of the page they link to?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if this is what you are looking for , but IBM Bluemix offers Blockchain as a Service and it also has some sample project implementations for you to start with . The projects are basic and provide the proof of concept, for you to build on.

Comment: IBM Bluemix's Blockchain as a service currently costs $1000 a month for a basic network, but the tutorials are free

Answer (score 1):

You can create a smart contract to share predictions,
and to do so solidity (contract-oriented, high-level language for implementing smart contracts) makes it really simple to create and deploy smart contracts to the blockchain.
And to create your own blockchain you can use azure services they are really good to start.